product.priceFormatStyle.currencyCode returns international currency code (PLN) instead of the local symbol (zł)
  var title3: String {
            switch ProductID(rawValue: product.id) {
            case .yearly:
                let yearlyPricePerWeek: Decimal = product.price / 52
                return "\(product.priceFormatStyle.format(yearlyPricePerWeek)) per week" // PLN
            case .weekly:
                return "\(product.displayPrice) per week" // zl
            case .weeklyWithTrial:
                return "then \(product.displayPrice) per week" // zl
            case .none:
                return ""
            }
        }


What is the device region set to? It's probably not set to a region where "zł" is used.

correct, that's the case, but how to align PLN with zl?

This is kind of the currency counterpart of time zone abbreviations. The "local" way of writing things is used when your device's region is set to certain regions, because otherwise it can get confusing.

If you want them to match, I'd suggest formatting everything with the priceFormatStyle. If you don't like that, then you'd need to get the App Store locale, and set that as the locale of the format. Previously you could get this by SKProduct.priceLocale, but I don't know how to do it using StoreKit 2.

Actually there is Storefront.current?.countryCode. It's a alpha-3 (3 letter) country code, and I think you can just pass that to Locale(identifier:), but I'm not sure.

They use different formats, so will not help here
